# Scala object oriented programming

Tags: scala, list, oop

In object oriented programming, Objects have their own state and behaviours. The Objects state is stored within instance variables and we use can use `objectname` to reference them.

`instance.variablename` notation is used to reference fields and instance methods are invoked by `objectname.instancemethodname(parm..)`.

However in here `Scala` there are other notations.

As an example: in `Scala` List I have come across the following notation:

`l filter p`

In here, `l` is the name of list instance and `p` is argument.

This scenario will return a list of elements that satisfy the predicate `p`.

So my question is what is that notaion and what does it mean?

Comment: How is one supposed to read this no-punctuation "paragraph" (if you can even call it a paragraph) ? Work on it to make it readable.

Comment: okay i agreed with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scala compiler rewrites `l filter p` to `l.filter(p)`, they are therefore treated the same at runtime however they look different to the reader and are thus a choice of programming style that affects the readability of the code.

Scala calls this style of invocation '[infix notation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html)' and it is intended to support methods as operations such as `+` and `*`.  In Java, operators such as `+` are provided by the JVM, however in Scala they may be defined on a class and then called using the same syntax as though the operator was defined by the JVM in Java.

For example:

```
case class Foo( v:String ) {
    def +(o:Foo) = Foo(v + o.v)
}

Foo("a").+(Foo("b")) // equals Foo("ab")
Foo("a") + Foo("b") // equals Foo("ab")
```

Comment: Well... just a minor detail - this is taken care by Scala parser and not the compiler.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh the parser is part of the compiler.